# Reverse int without conversion but it returns 0. Why?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to reverse integer values without converting to string and then back to int. Correct me if I'm wrong but that's costly & unnecessary. I tried this function and a console.log within the while and just after it returns, for example, 5 (if n = 5) --- but the return value is 0. Why?

```
function reverseInt(n) {
  const ten = 10;
  const zero = 0;
  // No need to convert, which is expensive
  let rev_num = zero;
  while (n > zero) {
    rev_num = rev_num * ten + (n % ten);
    n = Math.floor(n / ten);
  }

  return rev_num * Math.sign(n);
}
```

I was expecting 5, not 0.

Comment: `Math.floor(n / ten)` is `Math.floor(5 / 10)` is `Math.floor(0.5)` is `0`. `Math.sign(n)` is `Math.sign(0)` is `0`. Learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs). See [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](/q/25385173/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

`Math.sign` returns `0` since `n` is 0 at the end of the loop. Extract the sign before iterating instead.

```js
function reverseInt(n) {
  const ten = 10;
  const zero = 0;
  const sign = Math.sign(n);
  n = Math.abs(n);
  let rev_num = zero;
  while (n > zero) {
    rev_num = rev_num * ten + (n % ten);
    n = Math.floor(n / ten);
  }

  return rev_num * sign;
}
console.log(reverseInt(123));
```